# Core Location delegate method: "locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:" is called when the location manager is initialized.

Tags: ios, core-location

Why does this happen and why doesn't the Apple documentation include this?

Very puzzled.

Comment: it's usual if you are setting the delegate and allow or disallow the permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift LocationManager didChangeAuthorizationStatus Always Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106341/swift-locationmanager-didchangeauthorizationstatus-always-called)